# Resubscribe a Contact on the Global Unsubcribed List

Tags: marketing-cloud

So, I'm testing out my instance of Marketing Cloud and I unsubscribed from an email. Our set-up is it automatically unsubscribes a user and adds them to the Global Unsubscribed list.

I tried to import a CSV file with my email address, subscriber key, and status to change it from "Unsubscribed" to "Active" but that doesn't work.

How do I add myself back / remove myself from the Global Unsubscribed list?

Comment: If you just need to make yourself active again, go to All Subscribers list and search for your email address. You can change your status there manually. That is, if you mean the All Subscribers with "Global Unsubscribed list". For the CSV Import: that should work as well. Have you tried sending yourself an email? It could be that the status in the frontend is just not shown correctly. At least that was a problem a few months/ years ago.

Comment: @DonL - I tried that - going to All Subscribers and manually changing my status but it's blocked. So, I deleted myself and now I'm trying to add myself back and I get this message "This subscriber exists on the global unsubscribe list and cannot be added."

Comment: Do you have an option for 'Global Unsubscribe Management' in Email Studio under the Admin tab?

Answer (score 1):

Global Unsubscribe Lists are a system-wide list and affect all Accounts. Subscribers on these lists have requested no communication from any Account in the Marketing Cloud system.  To remove a subscriber from the Marketing Cloud global unsubscribe list, the subscriber must send an email to abuse@abuse.salesforce.com from the email address in question stating that they wish to be removed from said global unsubscribe list.

Please refer the following article, I hope it helps and it isn't too little too late
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318940&type=1&mode=1